# 3-number score?

Tags: cricket, scoring

I'm reading some novels by Hugh de Selincourt about village cricket in England. The scores are given as three numbers (e.g. 37—3—13). The first two seem to be runs so far (37) and wickets lost (3). What is the third number (13)?

Comment: Maybe runs-wickets-overs?

Answer (score 1):

The third number will be the number of overs completed.

While village cricket can take a number of forms, the number of overs played is always somewhat limited.

Village cricket was playing 20-over games long before it was popularised as a professional T20 format.  The planned time is often just a Sunday afternoon, or a game will start at 6pm after work - of course there is only available light.  Then due to the vagaries of summer weather, often games are shortened at the agreement of the two captains to fewer overs to ensure both teams get an innings in the available playing time.